# NameError (uninitialized constant Sprockets::Secretary): in TeamBox (crewmate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

I am trying to run the TeamBox fork [crewmate](https://github.com/crewmate/crewmate) on branch `master`, which uses Rails 3.0.20. 
Running in Development on my machine, when I open any page in the browser, the log shows the following entries:

```
  NameError (uninitialized constant Sprockets::Secretary):
  rake (0.9.2) lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
  sprockets-rails (0.0.1) lib/sprocket.rb:38:in `secretary'
  app/controllers/sprockets_controller.rb:14:in `send'
  app/controllers/sprockets_controller.rb:14:in `show'
  app/controllers/sprockets_controller.rb:6:in `index'
...
```

This happens both when I specify Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.3 in the Gemfile. 
On the browser, the result is that the javascript console logs the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
Localhost:3000/sprockets.js
```

I don't know if anyone can point me to the solution specifically for crewbox or more in general for Rails. 
What is this "Secretary" missing?

I tried updating to a more recent version of `sprocket-rails`, however by doing so the problem is that the `sprockets_include_tag` throws an exception (looks like it does not exist anymore).

Having a suggestion about how to replace the `sprockets_include_tag` with something else in a more recent version of `sprocket-rails` may do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this using sprockets 1.0.2

https://github.com/crewmate/crewmate/commit/540c60ea7d755396ead475aff3a9c82e176cdbff

The idea with crewmate project is update to more recently versions of ruby and rails. Is not an easy work but we hope accomplish this as far as possible. All help is welcome :D

Comment: For everyone looking to solve the problem and make Crewmate work with 1.9.3, don't just focus on sprockets 1.0.2 but the entire Gemfile linked in the answer (plus `bundle update`) makes the app work as intended.